# Docker Swarm : how to fix a swarm network name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack, docker-network

I'm using **Docker swarm** ,
There , within my ***docker-compose*** file i'm declaring a netwrk configuration:

```
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    networks:
     - myNetwork
    ...
networks:
  myNetwork:
     driver : overlay
```

After that i'm running : `docker stack deploy myStack -c myComposefile.yml`

The probleme that the resulting network is this :

```
    NETWORK ID          NAME                  DRIVER              SCOPE
    nu0iykhv5ewn        myStack_myNetwork     overlay             swarm
```

My problem is in the name of this network : "**myStack_myNetwork**"

How may i fix it to be only : "**myNetwork**"

Since i'm reusing this network in other stacks.

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1):

Create your shared network with `docker network create` (doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)) and define the network in the docker compose file as external (doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network))